# Tamanho da fonte do android influenciando na navbar do app

Tags: android, angularjs, apache-cordova, materialize

Estou desenvolvendo um app híbrido com Cordova utilizando AngularJs com Materialize.
Nele tem uma navbar com o botão de abrir o menu lateral e o titulo da página. Está funcionando tudo normal, porém uso no meu celular android as fontes menores, e com isso o conteúdo dessa navbar (botão do menu e titulo) ficam desalinhados como na imagem. Como posso resolver isso?

PS: sei que não é a melhor forma de desenvolver um app, mas é o que dá pra fazer pelo prazo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi desalinhado? os ítens do menu, ou o ícone em relação ao titulo?

Comment: O botão do menu e título da página em relação a navbar (está mais ao topo).
Um amigo meu está desenvolvendo nativamente e vi que a mudança de tamanho da fonte nas definições do aparelho não interferem no conteúdo da navbar.

Comment: poste o código da sua `navbar` com os botões, só coma imagem fica difícil ajudar.